# Python - Replace subprocess source files

Tags: python, multiprocessing, updates

I am trying to write a program where I have say two files, one called `launcher.py` and another called `sysupdate.py` where `launcher` spawns subprocesses to run concurrently (including sysupdate) and `sysupdate` listens on the network for a zipped software update file. When `sysupdate` receives an update file, it needs to be able to kill/pause the other processes (created by `launcher`), replace their source code files, and then restart them. I am struggling to find a neat way of accomplishing this, and was wondering if anyone had any suggestions as to how I could accomplish this?

I should mention that these subprocesses are designed to loop indefinitely, and therefore I can't wait for them to exit unfortunately, I need to be able to manually kill them, replace their source files, and then restart them.

While the subprocesses are running, I need the launcher to be able to 'keep them alive', so if they die for any reason then they should be restarted. Obviously, I need this behaviour to be paused when they are killed for a software update. This code is for an always-on sensor system, hence why I need the consistent looping and restarting.

For example:

launcher.py:

```py
def launch_threads():   
    # Reading thread
    try:
        readthread = Process(target=read_loop, args=(sendqueue, mqttqueue))
        processes.append(readthread)
    except Exception as ex:
        log("Read process creation failed: " + str(ex), 3)
        
    # ..... Other threads/processes here
    
    # System Update Thread
    try:
        global updatethread
        updatethread = Process(target=update_loop, args=(updatequeue,))
        processes.append(updatethread)
    except Exception as ex:
        log("Software updater process creation failed: " + str(ex), 3)

    return processes


if __name__ == '__main__':
        processes = launch_threads()
        for p in processes:
            p.start()
        for p in processes:              # Here I have it trying to keep processes alive permanently, .. 
            p.join()                     # .. I need a way to 'pause' this
            if not p.is_alive():
                p.start()
```

sysupdate.py:

```py
def update_loop():

    wait_for_zip_on_network()
    extract_zip()
    
    kill_processes()           # Need sysupdate to be able to tell 'launcher' to kill/pause the processes

    replace_source_files()

    resume_processes()         # Tell 'launcher' to resume/restart the processes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`launch_threads` may be a misnomer since you are launching processes and not threads. I am assuming you are launching some number of these that can be assigned to variable `N_TASKS` and one additional process represented by `update_loop` and thus the total number of processes is `N_TASKS` + 1. Furthermore, I will assume that these `N_TASKS` processes would ultimately complete assuming no source updates. My suggestion is then to use a multiprocessing pool, which conveniently provides several facilities that make our job a bit simpler. I would also use a modified version of `update_loop` that just listens for changes, updates the source and terminates but can be restarted:

**sysupdate.py**

```py
def modified_update():
    zip_file = wait_for_zip_on_network()
    return zip_file
```

Then we use the `Pool` class from the `multiprocessing` module with various callbacks so we can tell when various submitted tasks have completed. We want to wait for either the completion of the `modified_update` task or *all* of the "regular" tasks. In either case we terminate all outstanding tasks but in the first case we restart all the tasks and in the second case we are through:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from threading import Event

# the number of processes that need to run besides the modified_update process:
N_TASKS = 4

completed_event = None
completed_count = 0

def regular_task_completed_callback(result):
    global completed_count, completed_event
    completed_count += 1
    if completed_count == N_TASKS:
        completed_event.set() # we are throug with all the tasks

def new_source_files_callback(zip_file):
    global completed_event
    extract_zip(zip_file)
    replace_source_files()
    completed_event.set()

def launch_threads():
    global completed_event, completed_count
    POOLSIZE = N_TASKS + 1
    while True:
        completed_event = Event()
        completed_count = 0
        pool = Pool(POOLSIZE)
        # start the "regular" processes:
        pool.apply_async(read_loop, args=(sendqueue, mqttqueue), callback=regular_task_completed_callback)
        # etc.
        # start modified update_loop:
        pool.apply_async(modified_update, callback=new_source_files_callback)
        # wait for either the source files to have changed or the "regular" tasks to have completed:
        completed_event.wait()
        # terminate all outstanding tasks
        pool.terminate()
        if completed_count == N_TASKS: # all the "regular" tasks have completed
            return # we are done
        # else we start all over again


if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes = launch_threads()
```

**Update**

If the "regular" tasks never terminate, then that greatly simplified the logic. `modified_update` becomes:

**sysupdate.py**

```py
def modified_update():
    zip_file = wait_for_zip_on_network()
    extract_zip(zip_file)
    replace_source_files()
```

And then:

**launcher.py**

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool


def launch_threads():
    # the number of processes that need to run besides the modified_update process:
    N_TASKS = 4
    POOLSIZE = N_TASKS + 1
    while True:
        pool = Pool(POOLSIZE)
        # start the "regular" processes:
        pool.apply_async(read_loop, args=(sendqueue, mqttqueue))
        # etc.
        # start modified_update:
        result = pool.apply_async(modified_update)
        result.get() # wait for modified_update to complete
        # terminate all outstanding (i.e. "regular") tasks
        pool.terminate()
        # and start all over


if __name__ == '__main__':
    launch_threads()
```

**Note**

Since I am now using fewer `Pool` facilities, you *could* go back to starting individual `Process` instances. The gist of what is being done is:

1. `modified_update` no longer loops but terminates after it does its source updates.
2. `launch_threads` consists of a loop that launches the "regular" and `modified_update` processes and waits for the `modified_update` to complete signifying that a source update has taken place. As a result all the "regular" processes must be terminated and everything starts all over again. Using a pool just simplifies keeping track of all the processes and terminating them with one call.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! Yes, threads just an artifact from where I was using the multithreading module previously and just haven't renamed everything yet! Your answer looks really good, however I think I forgot to mention that thse processes don't finish. They are designed to loop indefinitely until killed to serve diferent functions in the system (it's an always-on sensor system), hence why I need to 'stop' them, and then restart them. My apologies for not mentioning that. I also need the launcher to prevent them from dying, and restart them if they do. That's one of my main problems :/

Comment: Just a small detail you forgot to mention. But if the source changes, don't you have to restart the programs? The code should work even if the "regular" programs never terminate. But as soon as it is detected that there is a new zip file, everything *will* be restarted. I don't know of any other way. BTW, `replace_source_files` was moved to the callback because if all the "regular" tasks finished and I then called `terminate` and the `modified_update` task was in the middle of updating source, that would not be a good thing. But now `terminate` will block if a callback is currently executing.

Comment: Your own code references function `kill_processes` and you have a comment **restart the processes**. What am I to think?

Comment: I'm so sorry for the confusion, I must've been a little tired and stressed when I wrote the question last night. I see what you mean about how it could still work though, I will implement your code and let you know how it goes. Thank you so much for your help so far!

Comment: There is an update to the code that will be greatly simplified.